# Installing R packages on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, packages

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 with LAMP setup and working on a website.The code execution halted and the log file **error.log** shows package installation issue. Specifically,

```
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called 'ggplot2'
```

Though I have ggplot2 installed locally, I couldn't find any thread or documents related to installation of package on server. If anyone can direct me the r package installation to solve the issue, it would be great.

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-install-and-load-ggplot2-in-r/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Earlier, I used the commands in the link to install ggplot2 package locally. However, I am not sure how to make apache recognize the package. As mentioned in the post, error.log saying that execution halted because there is no package installed.

Comment: Solved the issue with the help of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673000/rscript-there-is-no-package-called